# $\pi$, disjunctive numbers, and finite sequences of given length

Tags: number-theory, pi, computational-mathematics

It is an open problem whether the number $\pi$ is disjunctive in base $10$, i.e., whether every finite sequence appears (at least once) in the base $10$ expansion of $\pi$. Of course, every sequence of length $1$ appears, and it is readily checked that so does every sequence of length $2$. I guess the same can be easily checked for other small lengths, and has surely been done before. So, my question is the following:

> For which natural numbers $n$ is it known that every sequence of length $n$ appears in the base $10$ expansion of $\pi$?

Searching the internet somewhat longer I found that this is known to be true for $n$ at most $7$. Surely there must be much better bounds...

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations) for a bit of background information...

Comment: Quoted from above:
there's no particular reason for the digits of π to have any special pattern to them, so mathematicians expect that the digits of π more or less "behave randomly," and a random sequence of digits contains every possible finite string of digits with probability 1 by Borel's normal number theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples

Comment: @AlexR: How are your comments related to the question?

Comment: I just happened to stumble across this (old) question, which is related to yours. It does not provide answers, but it provides references. I thought this might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This answer is taken from [the corresponding question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/142194) on MO.)*

This is known since 2010 at least for $n\leq 11$ -- see [this entry](http://oeis.org/A036903) in the OEIS or F. Bellards's [page about digits of $\pi$](http://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/pidigits.html). In fact, every sequence of length $11$ occurs once in the first $2\ 512\ 258\ 603\ 207$ digits of $\pi$.