# A ray and a line intersect, and the usefulness of geometric, euclidian beyond infinity?

Tags: geometry, infinity

A 2D euclidian plane R<sup>2</sup> contains a line and a ray.

The line is vertical and positioned where $x = 0$. The point on the line where $y = 0$ is labelled $m$.

One end of the ray is at $(x, y) = (1, 0)$ pointing in the negative $x$ direction.

The ray intersects the line at a distance along the line of $n$ from $m$. Initially $n = 0$ but when turning the ray the value of $n$ changes.

When rotated far enough the ray becomes parallel to the line. As we tend towards this configuration $n$ tends towards infinity.

I've heard the stronger term used that "parallel lines meet at infinity" even outside of the context of projective geometry. As infinity is a single value at both ends of the real number-line, presumably with parallel lines all 4 line ends in question meet at that infinite point.

Q: Returning to the case with a line and a ray, is it ever well defined and useful to consider (name and use) the value of $n$ reached when the ray is pointing away from the line? For example along the $x$ axis in the positive direction.

Comment: Did you mean the ray starts at $(x,y)=(1,0)$?

Comment: This might not be what we're looking for, but certainly the *asymptotic behavior* of functions tending to infinity - especially the *comparative* asymptotic behavior - can be quite interesting. Specifically, what you have in this case is (for example, framing things in terms of rotation) a function from $[0,{\pi\over 2})$ to $\mathbb{R}$ sending a given angle to the distance from the origin of the resulting "meeting point." Rotating at a different speed, or using a different ray, or etc. will change the behavior of the resulting function. (cont'd)

Comment: The key point here is that we don't want to distinguish between the "infinities" these functions tend to (indeed, under the most natural interpretation they're all the *same* "infinity"!), but rather the *manner in which* they tend to infinity. (If you *really* want to "assign an infinity" to a function, you can do something like this via nonstandard analysis, but all you're really doing is rephrasing the asymptotic behavior.) I don't know about the specific example you're describing, but certainly general asymptotic analysis is quite important.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've now fixed the typo :-/ I'm just reading Noah's comment :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661855/is-it-faster-to-count-to-the-infinite-going-one-by-one-or-two-by-two/662220#662220

Comment: You might find it useful to read up on one-point compactification.