# Pi vs Irrational Numbers

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, pi, transcendental-numbers

I'm very curious about the relationship between $\pi$ and irrational numbers in general. Whether [$\pi$ contains all possible number combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations/216350#216350) is unknown, but expected to be true.

What "kind" of irrationals numbers does $\pi$ contain? Consider the set
$$
S=\{\alpha\pi+\beta\,\mid\,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Q},\,\alpha\neq 0\}.
$$
Since [$\pi$ contains only countably many infinite digit strings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490079/pi-might-contain-all-finite-sets-can-it-also-contain-infinite-sets), we have that $S\subsetneq\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. What else can we say about $S$?

For example, one may ask the following questions:

- Is it true that $\sqrt{2}\in S$? If not, what prevents it from being true?
- What about $e$? Are $S$ and transcendental numbers relatable somehow?

Any deeper insights are appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt2\notin S$, since that would mean that $\pi$ would be algebraic. The answer to your second question is much much harder to show, but it is also false.

Comment: It seems like it would be hard to find any special properties of $S$ that don’t also apply to other sets containing all numbers in the form $a\alpha+b$ for some irrational $\alpha$.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer In fact, if we defined $S$ with (fore example) $\sqrt 2$ instead of $\pi$, it would be a subfield of $\Bbb R$, i.e., something much more specific. The fact that $\pi $ is transcendental over $\Bbb Q$ means quite precisely that we can indeed view $\pi$ as a generic variable $X$ here

Comment: You might find it interesting to consider and compare the continued fraction representations of various irrationals. For example, for non-zero $\alpha$, $\alpha\sqrt{2}+\beta$ is an irrational solution of a quadratic equation and so its continued fraction representation is periodic, whereas that of $e$ exhibits a curious pattern, etc.