# Can we show that the decimal expansion of $\pi$ doesn't occur in the decimal expansion of the Champernowne constant?

Tags: number-theory, pi

This question was inspired by an answer and some comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313407/decimal-expansion-of-pi).

Recall that the Champernowne constant is obtained by concatenating all natural numbers written in base 10 and then put $0.$ in front, that is,
$$C_{10}=0.123456789101112131415161718192021222324\cdots$$

The question is does the decimal expansion of $\pi$ occur as a tail of this number? By which I mean is there some $n$ such that $$\pi=C_{10}\cdot10^{n+1}-10\cdot\lfloor C_{10}\cdot10^n\rfloor$$

Now it is obvious that any finite initial string of $\pi$ occurs in $C_{10}$. Not only that, it also occurs infinitely often (that's just because any finite string of numbers occurs infinitely often in $C_{10}$).

Hagen von Eitzen (who's answer inspired this question) also notes that proving that $\pi$ does occur as the tail of $C_{10}$ would imply that $\pi$ is base-$10$-normal which is an open question see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51853/what-is-the-state-of-our-ignorance-about-the-normality-of-pi), so it is very unlikely we can prove that. He also notes "that if such a position exists [one where $C_{10}$ starts giving the digits of $\pi$] (somewhere in the middle of an $n$-digit integer, say) then the first $10^{n/2}n$ or so digits of $\pi$ turn out nearly regular and this should give rise to an unusually good rational approximation."

I tried to consider if there might be some relationship with relative algebraicity, but even in that direction little seems to be known since it is unknown even whether $\pi$ is algebraic over $e$.

In conclusion it seems intuitively extremely unlikely that $\pi$ would occur in $C_{10}$, but I can't think of a proof that it doesn't. A good answer would also be a reduction of this problem to some known open problem (note that we need to reduce that $\pi$ **is not** the tail of $C_{10}$).

PS If someone can come up with better tags please have a go at it.

Comment: I do not understand: if we could prove that π occurs as the tail of Champernowne, we could prove that π is base-10-normal. Since the latter result is unknown, the answer to the question in your title is (trivially) "No we cannot".

Comment: @did Nope. That's what I address in the last paragraph. The answer to the question "Can we prove $\pi$ is the tail of $C_{10}$?" is no. But the question asks "Can we prove $\pi$ is **not** the tail of $C_{10}$?" and the answer to that might be yes.

Comment: @Did Essentially this turns fully on what the correct answer is. If it is true that $\pi$ is the tail of $C_{10}$ than bad luck, since proving that would mean solving whether or not $\pi$ is base-$10$-normal, but if it's true (as I strongly believe) that $\pi$ is not the tail of $C_{10}$ there might be an easy proof of that since it doesn't imply anything hard as far as we know.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase heavily your question, which could read: *Since the normality in base 10 of π is unknown and Champernowne is normal, there is no proof that π occurs as the tail of Champernowne. Is there a proof that π does not occur as the tail of Champernowne?*

Comment: @Did Why? The question as it stands currently asks exactly what it should and the things you added to the title are detailed in the post. I felt that title was way too long as is.

Comment: ?? Nobody added anything to the title. Whatever.

Comment: @did sorry if I misphrased my comment. I thought you meant I should change the title to what you said I should rephrase the question as. I did not intend to come across hostile and I apologize if I did.

Comment: What you call "relative algebraicity" is actually called [algebraic dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence). There is no notion of number algebraic over another number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there were such an equality, then the Champernowne number would be equally well (up to a scaling constant) approximated by rational numbers as $\pi$. In particular, they would have the same irrationality measure. However, the Champernowne constant is known to have irrationality measure $10$, whereas the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is expected to be $2$, and is known to be at most $7.6063\ldots$