# Does pi have any combination of two numbers that the distance between them equal some natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pi

Let's assume that $\pi = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^i}.$ Also, let $n$ be an arbitrary natural number.

Is there $j,k,m \in \mathbb{N}, (j < k < m)$ such that $|b_1 - b_{2}| = n$ when $b_1 = \sum_{i=j}^{k}a_i10^{k-i}, b_2 = \sum_{i=k+1}^{m}a_i10^{m-i}$?

**for example**:   0.14(15)(92)... so for |92-15|=77 there are j,k,m as wanted.

the **original question** was:

can a number $x = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_i}{10^i}$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb N\ \exists j,k,m \in \mathbb{N}, (j < k < m)$ such that $|b_1 - b_{2}| = n$ when $b_1 = \sum_{i=j}^{k}a_i10^{k-i}, b_2 = \sum_{i=k+1}^{m}a_i10^{m-i}$ is a rational number?

i would like for now a solution only for the first part but any solution will be welcomed.

Comment: To clarify, $3.14(15)(92)$ would constitute a positive answer if it were true that $|92-15|=4$?

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to asking whether or not $\pi$ is normal (which is, AFAIK, unknown)?  or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: That may not be less difficult than Riemann Hypothesis, say, but it's far less interesting. The decimal system if just one of countably infinite ones, so who really cares?

Comment: respond to Hagen von Eitzen : why?, i said for any arbitrary n natural number so for 77 (which is natural) the statement is true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is widely believed that the decimal expansion of $\pi$ contains every string of digits, see for example [Does Pi contain all possible number combinations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations)

If one accepts this as true, your statement follows readily. 
However, to show this is considered as very difficult.

While your problem is somewhat simpler, I am afraid it is sufficiently similar that it is too difficult to be answered definitely at this point in time (and likely quite a bit of time in the future).