# Is this proof that $\pi$ does not contain all possible combination correct?

Tags: pi

I came across this meme today:

[image]

The counterproof is very trivial, but I see no one disproves it. Some even say that the meme might be true. Well, $\pi$ cannot contain itself.

Well, everything means $\pi$ might contain $\pi$ somewhere in it. Say it starts going $\pi=3.1415...31415...$ again on the $p$ digit. Then it will have to do the same at the $2p$ digit, since the "nested $\pi$" also contains another $\pi$ in it. $\pi$ then will be rational, which is wrong. Thus $\pi$ does not contain all possible combination.

Is this proof correct? I'm not a mathematician so I'm afraid I make silly mistakes.

Comment: The claim is that it contains all finite substrings, which while conjectured, has not yet been proven.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't claim to prove that. I guess I only attempt to prove (if correct) that it doesn't contain one infinite substring, which mean it does not contain "everything".

Comment: well, it does contain the ASCII-encoded text for the definition of $\pi$...

Comment: So "all possible combination" only applies to finite sequence of numbers? I'm loose on the mathematical terms (obviously lol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure it has $31415$ again in the decimal expansion, but why should it continue $926535$ after that?  Sometimes it will, but it will eventually diverge from the decimals at the start.  You have not made any argument that when you see $31415$ it should repeat from there and in fact it will not.

You are correct that $\pi$ cannot contain itself.  The [claim, not known to be true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations?rq=1), is that $\pi$ contains all finite sequences of digits.

Comment: @D.Tran It's not you, it's the meme. It's romanticised to the point of ridiculousness, and is not interested in actually stating the result it's claiming, or in acknowledging that the result is merely an open problem. What it doesn't say is that *most* numbers actually do have this property (which is known)! It's just unknown whether $\pi$ is one of these numbers (called "normal numbers").

Answer (score 2):

An infinite non-repeating decimal does **not** imply that every possible number combination exists somewhere. Consider the number: $0.101001000100001\ldots$, the pattern is easy to spot, but this is an irrational number because...you guessed it...it's an infinite, non-repeating decimal.

It is conjectured that $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), but this has not been proven. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51853/what-is-the-state-of-our-ignorance-about-the-normality-of-pi) is an old question from MathOverflow with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{n} = tr_{n}(\pi)$

$a_{1} = 3.1$

$a_{2} = 3.14$

$a_{3} = 3.141$

$a_{4} = 3.1415$

$lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = \pi$

Then, suppose that $\pi$ contains all finite sequences of digits.

If $\pi$ not contains himself, then there exist $m = max\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : a_{n} \in$ digits of $\pi \}$

But then $a_{m+1}$ is a finite sequence, so is in digits of $\pi$

Then $m$ is not the max, that is a contradiction.

Then $\pi$ contain $\pi$

Well this is in the hypothetical case in which it happens that $\pi$ contains all finite sequences of digits